# Amplify CLI: An error occurred when pushing the storage resource: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logicalId')

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am working on a fresh copy of our dev AWS Amplify backend environment on an M1 mac. When I run `amplify add storage` and create a new DynamoDB table everything works as expected. But when I run `amplify push storage`, I get the attached success-then-error message, which says

> GraphQL schema compiled successfully.
>
> Edit your schema at < filepath1 > or place .graphql files in a directory at < filepath2 >
>
> An error occurred when pushing the storage resource: Cannot read
> properties of undefined (reading 'logicalId')

I've never seen this error, and have no idea what logicalId is. I am on the latest version of the Amplify CLI, and if I remove and re-add the storage, it still happens.

Can anyone help me debug this?

[image: Amplify Error]

Comment: I'd pull the current `env` to a new folder, and try pushing. Then if that works, push all your changes, delete the amplify folder, and then pull the `env` into your working project. If you're on vscode, your IDE will show the changes you'll need to add back. Then try again